# Command line for using remote SQL database

Tags: java, mysql

I'm currently working on a project for conducting online test for our college,

I have successfully performed the test using our internal servers, now I need to host online through private hosting services, everything is ready except for the Database.

The database is created using the same service provider but I don't know how to modify the command line for remote hosting.

```
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/placement","username","password");
```

This is the command line I used in our internal server, now how to modify it for remote SQL database

The remote db name is "epiz_22735410_placement_db"

The host name is "sql104.epizy.com"

Comment: The first place to look would normally be the documentation, which in this case contains [a detailed reference on the form of the database URL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could follow this pattern:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://HOST:PORT/DATABASE";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of localhost use `sql104.epizy.com` everything else should stay the same if it's working on local (assuming your credentials etc are the same as local)

e.g.

`mysql://sql104.epizy.com:3306/epiz_22735410_placement_db","username","password");`

Comment: What about the port 3306 ...?

Comment: you'll need to add the post as well, mysql is usually opened on port 3306